# How to run a Java applet in Apache Wicket 6.5?

Tags: java, applet, wicket, wicket-6

I am trying to run an applet in a web application using Apache Wicket. I put MyApplet.jar and the html page in the same directory but I got this error when deploying the page:

```
NullPointerException : An error occurred while running the application
```

Any help please ?? How can I track down to the point where the error happens, or what else can I try?

Thanks in advance.

My HTML page is

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">


<body>
<wicket:extend>  

  <div class="intro-lead-in">Signing your Documents</div>  

        <applet code=wct.applet.Welcome.class
            archive="MyApplet3.jar"

            codebase="http://localhost:8080/wicketspringdemo"
            width=550 height=300>
        </applet>

</wicket:extend>



</body>
```

Comment: Added tags; slight language and brand name improvement; formed title to a question; tried to narrow down the question

Comment: Show us the stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience serving applets from Wicket. It can get nasty, because there are many things that need to be setup correctly.

To tackle this kind of problem:

1. Read and try to understand the stacktrace
2. Check if the applet works in a applet-viewer (without embedding in HTML)
3. Check if it works in a static HTML page to make sure it is a Wicket-related problem, not a java-applet-specific problem
4. If it works in a static page, you can also save the page generated by Wicket and try if that works.
5. Check if your java-applet-security settings allow running the applet (java-plugin console)

**EDIT**

This is my code (wicket 1.2, but should be upgradable)

```
<applet wicket:id="applet" codebase="applet"
    code="nl.valuecare.PasteApplet" width="20" height="20"
    archive="pasteappletsigned.jar" mayscript="mayscript"> </applet>
```

Where `codebase` is relativa path in the `WAR`

The `mayscript` is to allow java <> javascript communication.

I signed the `Applet` with a valid Code Signing Certificat because I need elevated permissions.

Maybe it is not allowed to use a absolute codebase?

Comment: 1. i have just "NullPointerException : An error occurred while running the application"   
2. the applet works correctly in applet-viewer.
3. it works fine in a static HTML page .
4. i have the same code in wicket page and html page.
5. i add the url in java-applet-security 
but always dosen't work :(

Comment: At step 4: if you create a simple WebPage (no extra wicket-components, just the static html you tried in step 3). What does it do?

Comment: I try with an applet to just show me "Hello world"
this is my html page 'code'

Comment: I can access my jar with an url
i tried it with a simple page but it dosen't work . "NullPointerException : An error occurred while running the application".  @RobAu